В чем смысл своей реализации контейнеров в QT?
Я не очень могу понять, чем это обусловлено, кто-то может четко сказать, чем тогда руководствовались, что им потребовалось написать свой велосипед, плюс я заметил, что это не только в qt, но и в некоторых других фреймворках.
Была ли какая-то проблема с STL в то время?

Не видя кода ничего точно сказать нельзя. Можно только предполагать. Может проблема, может амбиции (учтите, есть люди которым просто нравится писать свой код), а может более эффективная реализация для тех задач, где эти контейнеры использовались.

+. @den могу лишь добавить пару наводок для "погуглить": copy-on-write механика, потокобезопасность, эффективные хэш-таблицы. Для конкретно/особенно Qt: сигналы и слоты (в частности "Регистрация пользовательского класса в Qt"  )

@sibedir в том то и дело, что я все это знаю, но так и не понимаю, почему во многих фреймворках написаны свои реализации

Qt создавался в начале 90-х, STL тогда еще находился в стадии развития.

Что не так с вопросом? почему -? вместо того, чтобы минусовать, лучше бы ответил и помог....

"ему во многих фреймворках написаны свои реализации" ммм... Ну я всегда и полагал, что свои реализации (профессиональные) как-раз и пишут, потому что stl не имеет встроенными многих механик, которые нужны авторам.

@Den , кстати, "Что не так с вопросом? почему -?". На ваш вопрос на самом деле нельзя дать однозначный ответ
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

в то время еще не было C++11 и соответственно move семантики. Поэтому в Qt реалзвали контейнеры CoW

@SergeyTatarintsev спасибо
